# How to convert a floating point to hexadecimal (and back) in Delphi

Tags: delphi, floating-point, hex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Converting float or negative integer to hexadecimal in Borland Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2200876/converting-float-or-negative-integer-to-hexadecimal-in-borland-delphi)

Is there a function i can use to convert a floating point value to a hexadecimal value and back?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2200876

Comment: do you want to represent the memory bytes or the *actual* value as a hex string?

Comment: Maybe you don't understand the difference between binary and text representation of numeric values. I don't think you really need the hexadecimal representation of floating point values. Describe your real problem and you will get the useful answer.

Comment: As Paul said, a duplicate of your other post (that was answered). You were given links in that post to articles on converting floats to hex and back.

Answer (score 6):

```
procedure ShowBinaryRepresentation;
var
  S, S2: Single;
  I: Integer;
  D, D2: Double;
  I64: Int64;
begin
  S := -1.841;
  I := PInteger(@S)^;
  OutputWriteLine(Format('Single in binary represenation: %.8X', [I]));

  S2 := PSingle(@I)^;
  OutputWriteLine(Format('Converted back to single: %f', [S2]));

  D := -1.841E50;
  I64 := PInt64(@D)^;
  OutputWriteLine(Format('Double in binary represenation: %.16X', [I64]));

  D2 := PDouble(@I64)^;
  OutputWriteLine(Format('Converted back to double: %f', [D2]));
end;
```

```
Single in binary represenation: BFEBA5E3
Converted back to single: -1,84
Double in binary represenation: CA5F7DD860D57D4D
Converted back to double: -1,841E50
```

Answer (score 0):

Not floating point. There is inttohex to change integers (maybe int64 too) to hex strings.

Probably you need to pry apart the bits in the IEEE format double type and change them to hex which you then concat with a point inbetween.

If this is not the answer you are looking for, please specify what you mean by "hexadecimal value".

If you just want to convert it to an array of e.g. bytes, define a array of byte type with a suitable size (4 for single, 8 for double and 10 extended), and typecast.